# jQuery getting id of the element which is sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I got some div's which are sortable etc.. But they got all the same classes, so if I drag one, all the contents of the div's are hiding. I want to get 'id' of the div i'm dragging, and put it into `hide` and `show` function.

**It should be like this..**

jQuery code:

```
$("#column-right").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sort",
    handle: ".title",
    placeholder: "salih",
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function() {
        .click(function() {      // I know it is wrong but it should be like this
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        }
        $('id').hide();
    },
    stop: function() {
        .click(function() {   // same
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        }
        $('id').show();
    }
});
```

EDIT: Example my problem: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6TAa/)

Comment: Live example or fiddle will be helpful

Comment: you're using an ID to assign `sortable` and then attempting to get the  id of it. something isn't right with this. and then you are trying to hide the item being dragged at start, and show at end? that will confuse the hell out of the user

Comment: You should probably need to change this `var id = $(this).attr('id')` to `$(this).hide()` or `$(this).show()` inside your `click` events

Comment: The element you are moving gets a class of 'ui-sortable-helper'. There should only be one of those on the page. You should be able to use $('.ui-sortable-helper').hide() instead of trying to get the ID, but I am really struggling to understand what you are trying to do. If the dragged item is hidden, you won't be able to drop it somewhere because it will be display:none; Maybe you want to use visability:hidden instead ($('.ui-sortable-helper').css('visability','hidden');

Comment: Will it work for you? Changing `$('.contents').show() or hide()` to `$(this).find('.contents').show() or hide()`

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if this is something you were looking for: 
**JavaScript Code**

```
$("#column-left, #column-middle, #column-right").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sort",
    handle: ".title",
    placeholder: "salih",
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function() {
        $(this).find('.contents').hide();
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).find('.contents').show();
    }
});
$(".sort").disableSelection();
```

In general, `$(this).find('.contents')` will be exactly the child element (content) which you are dragging.
Also, I have merged your 3 identical methods into 1 avoiding duplicates and any mess in the code.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't the one that i'm searching for. For example look this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/u6TAa/2/


btw thanks for all one one method